# Add Custom User-Meta to the Users Admin page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a special form within my site that allows my users to enter a key.  I am using `add_user_meta()` to add the meta data into the database.  I want to be able to see this key when I click on users in the admin center.

How would I go about adding to this column?

Below is the meta data info im using

```
add_user_meta($userId,'code','12345');
```

We just want to be able to add it to the view on users.php in the table displaying username email and role.

I have used code like this to display the user id but I can not figure out how to display their meta.

```
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'pippin_add_user_id_column');
function pippin_add_user_id_column($columns) {
    $columns['user_id'] = 'User ID';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'pippin_show_user_id_column_content', 10, 3);
function pippin_show_user_id_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'user_id' == $column_name )
        return $user_id;
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

This example was created with the help of these two pages from the WordPress codex.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update

It is for displaying and updating the custom user meta data.

```
<?php

// Hooks near the bottom of profile page (if current user) 
add_action('show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');

// Hooks near the bottom of the profile page (if not current user) 
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');

// @param WP_User $user
function custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="code"><?php _e( 'Custom Meta' ); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="code" id="code" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'code', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}


// Hook is used to save custom fields that have been added to the WordPress profile page (if current user) 
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields' );

// Hook is used to save custom fields that have been added to the WordPress profile page (if not current user) 
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields' );

function update_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'code', $_POST['code'] );
}

?>
```

Comment: I was looking to add the field to users.php where it displays the username, email and roles. We do not want the ability to edit it.

Comment: So just use the first part of code for displaying it, and change the input element to something non editable.

Comment: I do not want to display it on user.php I want to display it on users.php.  This would be the page that displays all usernames, emails, and roles in a table.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above from [Mordred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911192/mordred) worked for me after changing the second **add_filter** to **add_action**. Here's the modified code:

```
function yoursite_manage_users_columns( $columns ) {

    // $columns is a key/value array of column slugs and names
    $columns[ 'custom_field' ] = 'Subscription';

    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'yoursite_manage_users_columns', 10, 1 );

function yoursite_manage_users_custom_column( $output, $column_key, $user_id ) {

    switch ( $column_key ) {
        case 'custom_field':
            $value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_field', true );

            return $value;
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    // if no column slug found, return default output value
    return $output;
}

add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'yoursite_manage_users_custom_column', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

To add custom user_meta fields to users.php you need to do the following:

```
function yoursite_manage_users_columns( $columns ) {

    // $columns is a key/value array of column slugs and names
    $columns[ 'custom_field' ] = 'Subscription';

    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'yoursite_manage_users_columns', 10, 1 );

function yoursite_manage_users_custom_column( $output, $column_key, $user_id ) {

    switch ( $column_key ) {
        case 'custom_field':
            $value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_field', true );

            return $value;
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    // if no column slug found, return default output value
    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'yoursite_manage_users_custom_column', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Realising this is a bit of an old thread, however I was stuck on a very similar problem, and thought I would share what I found which proved to be a very simple solution.

```
<?php
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'pippin_add_user_id_column');
function pippin_add_user_id_column($columns) {
    $columns['user_id'] = 'User ID';
    return $columns;
}    

add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'pippin_show_user_id_column_content', 10, 3);
function pippin_show_user_id_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( 'user_id' == $column_name )
        return $user_id;
    return $value;
}
?>
```

Credit: https://pippinsplugins.com/add-user-id-column-to-the-wordpress-users-table/

Comment: This is the exact same code in the original question, verbatim. It doesn't answer how to add a custom_meta field.

Answer (score -1):

To make the additional woocommerce fields editable you can use the following filter (in the example a custom field is added in the billing section).

```
add_filter('woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'add_woocommerce_customer_meta_fields');
    function add_woocommerce_customer_meta_fields($fields)
    {
      if (isset($fields['billing']['fields'])) {
        $fields['billing']['fields']['your_custom_meta'] = array(
          'label' => __('Friendly name', 'woocommerce'),
          'description' => ''
        );
      }
      return $fields;
    }
```

Comment: The original question is nothing to do with WooCommerce.